# Ajax/Jquery - Ajax processing before callback, beforeSend, ajaxStart, .always

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins, callback, ajax-request

I am currently having an issue with jquery's ajax call. What i'm trying to do is empty a few div's, hide a container, and then call the requested Ajax code to populate the div once again, and show it. However, my code is calling upon the request, and hides it while processing the ajax request causing the div's to empty...

Sample code with custom callback (not working):

```
// This is defined within an element and is retrieving properly as well
cleanInfo(getCharacter($this.attr('id')));

function cleanInfo(callback){
    // hide the container first, then empty and callback to ajax function
$('.sel_information_container').hide('slide', {direction: 'down'}, 'fast',function(){
    $('.sel_info_top').html('');
    $('.sel_info_description').html('');
    $('.skill_tree').html('');
    callback;
       // OR
}, callback);   
}

function getCharacter(id){

if(!id){
    id = 0;
}

$.ajax({
// path is defined in core file this works right as it's retrieving the data properly... and everything is        
    // and everything is right in php...
       url : _path + "/core/ajax.php",
       type : 'POST',
       data : { f: 'getCharacter', i: id },
       dataType : 'json',
       success :  function(data) {
        // if data error is sent back process it ...
        if(data.error){

            $('body').html(data.error);

        }else{
            // if no error populate and show the container
            $('.sel_info_top').html(data.info);
            $('.sel_info_description').html(data.desc);
            $('.skill_tree').html(data.skills);
            $('.sel_information_container').show('slide', {direction: 'down'}, 'slow');         
        }

    }
});

}
```

Sample code with ajaxSend/beforeSend/ajaxStart/always (not working):

```
// This is defined within an element and is retrieving properly as well
getCharacter($this.attr('id'));
// without callback and utilizing variable request...
function cleanInfo(){

$('.sel_information_container').hide('slide', {direction: 'down'}, 'fast',function(){
    $('.sel_info_top').html('');
    $('.sel_info_description').html('');
    $('.skill_tree').html('');
}); 
}

function getCharacter(id){

if(!id){
    id = 0;
}

    // Instead of attaching the results to the var, I have also ran beforeSend: cleanInfo() which 
    // does the exact same thing as the above...

var request = $.ajax({
// path is defined in core file this works right as it's retrieving the data properly... and everything is        
    // and everything is right in php...
       url : _path + "/core/ajax.php",
       type : 'POST',
       data : { f: 'getCharacter', i: id },
       dataType : 'json',
       success :  function(data) {

        if(data.error){

            $('body').html(data.error);

        }else{

            $('.sel_info_top').html(data.info);
            $('.sel_info_description').html(data.desc);
            $('.skill_tree').html(data.skills);
            $('.sel_information_container').show('slide', {direction: 'down'}, 'slow');         
        }

    }
});
    // ajaxSend, always, ajaxStart, all not working with this...
    request.ajaxSend(cleanInfo());

}
```

Any solutions people?

Answer (score 0):

Because the ajax call is asynchronous, the `getCharacter` call will return immediately.

I would move the hiding and emptying part into `beforeSend` in the `ajax` call, and add error handling to the `ajax` call also:

```
// This is defined within an element and is retrieving properly as well
cleanInfo($(this).attr('id'));

function cleanInfo(id){
   if(!id){
       id = 0;
   }

   $.ajax({
       url : _path + "/core/ajax.php",
       type : 'POST',
       data : { f: 'getCharacter', i: id },
       dataType : 'json',
       cache: 'false',
       beforeSend: function() {
                   console.log("Emptying");
                   // hide the container first, then empty and callback to ajax function
                   $('.sel_information_container').hide('slide', {direction: 'down'}, 'fast',function(){
                       $('.sel_info_top').html('');
                       $('.sel_info_description').html('');
                       $('.skill_tree').html('');
                   }
       },
       success :  function(data) {
            // if data error is sent back process it ...
            if(data.error){
                $('body').html(data.error);
            }else{
                // if no error populate and show the container
                console.log("Populating");
                $('.sel_info_top').html(data.info);
                $('.sel_info_description').html(data.desc);
                $('.skill_tree').html(data.skills);
                $('.sel_information_container').show('slide', {direction: 'down'}, 'slow');         
            }
       },
       error: function (xhr, textStatus, thrownError) {
         $('body').html("Error: " + xhr.status + " - " + thrownError);
       }
   });
}
```

Comment: so I would just set cache to false? i've tried beforeSend too, it's not working

Comment: Can you explain "not working"? Is the success function of the ajax not executing? `Cache: false` won't fix your problem - that was a copy paste from another piece of code. Also added in `error:` to the ajax call.